# On Dynamics Quick Create Form make 'Email' field mandatory using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

Hope all is well everyone!

Im practicing CRM Dynamics development, on the 'Contact' quick create form, I'm trying to achieve making the emailaddress1 field mandatory/setrequired only.

Currently my function below is making all of the form fields mandatory on the 'Contact' quick create form which I don't want it to do, I just want to make 'emailaddress1' field setrequired only, any suggestions?

```
function SetRequiredLevel()    
{
var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
for (var i in attributes) {
attributes[i].setRequiredLevel("required");
}
}

//Xrm.Page.getAttribute("emailaddress1").getValue();
```

[image: Screen shot is off all the form fields mandatory on the 'Contact' quick create]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XRM.Page is deprecated. You should use this form:

```
function displayName(executionContext)
{
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); // get formContext
    // use formContext instead of Xrm.Page  
    formContext.getAttribute("emailaddress1").setRequiredLevel("required");  
}
```

Comment: is the xrm.page object fully deprecated on UCI? @Eccountable

Comment: Not it is not. You probably have another few months before you will be required to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, and is making 'emailaddress1' mandatory.

```
function SetRequiredLevel()    
{
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("emailaddress1").setRequiredLevel("required");  
}
```

Comment: I recommend you start using the formContext, instead of Xrm.Page